# Using kubernetes volumes as local spark directory for executors to spill on

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm running Spark 3.1.3 on Kubernetes (version 1.21).

I'm trying to mount Kubernetes PVCs on my executors with the following configuration, inspired on the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/running-on-kubernetes.html#local-storage):

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.[VolumeName].options.claimName=OnDemand
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.[VolumeName].options.storageClass=someClaimName
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.[VolumeName].options.sizeLimit=100Gi
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.[VolumeName].mount.path=//local-data
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.[VolumeName].mount.readOnly=false
```

The `[VolumeName]` bit is crucial to my question.

**First test: non local volumes**

My first test was where `[VolumeName]` == `test`, so the first line of that block was:

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.test.options.claimName=OnDemand
```

This successfully mounted a volume of 100Gi at `/local-data` in my executors! The only problem is that my executors were still not using that as local directory to write their data to. This makes sense, as the docs specify that if you want your executors to use a k8s volume as a local directory, the `[VolumeName]` must start with `spark-local-dir-`.

**Second test: local volumes**

So my next test was to have `[VolumeName]` == `spark-local-dir-1`.

Upon doing this, I get the following logs in my `kubectl get events`:

```
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  0/30 nodes are available: 30 persistentvolumeclaim "eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1-pvc-0" not found.
0s          Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded    persistentvolumeclaim/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1-pvc-0          Successfully provisioned volume pvc-2ad06d14-1eaf-41c2-8e50-4a07b87fd7c4 using kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
0s          Normal    Scheduled                pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  Successfully assigned spark-namespace/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1 to fe5ab9bb-69a7-4a3b-9230-3a7cd01e4f18
0s          Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume   pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-2ad06d14-1eaf-41c2-8e50-4a07b87fd7c4"
0s          Normal    Pulling                  pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  Pulling image "our-repo/bbi-dios/spark:3.1.3"
0s          Normal    Pulled                   pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  Successfully pulled image "our-repo/bbi-dios/spark:3.1.3" in 97.72301ms
0s          Normal    Created                  pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  Created container spark-kubernetes-executor
0s          Normal    Started                  pod/eng-47c8e482f8775c25-exec-1                                  Started container spark-kubernetes-executor
```

It seems like, somehow, when I try to mount my some volumes as local volumes that this goes wrong.

**Third test: local volumes, second way**

I then tried to specify the local dir in another way, by setting the SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS environment variable in the executors. So, I simply used `[VolumeName]` == `test` (same as my first test) and I added one extra line:

```
--conf spark.executorEnv.SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/local-data
```

which should have as result that the executors write to that location. This still gives the same problems of starting up persistentVolumeClaims as in my second test.

So it seems like something is preventing me from using mounted volumes as local dir in spark executors. Does anyone have an idea of what can be going wrong here?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: what is your default storageclass ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the default storage class is, but we have specified the storage class as vspherestorage (from vmware). We've specified it like this: --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.storageClass=vspherestorage

Comment: The second method worked for me. Try using something other than "/local-data" for the mount path, "/opt/disk" worked for me. (I had put only the claim name and mount path as conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that my mounted volumes were being mounted with read only permissions, even though I was setting `spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.[VolumeName].mount.readOnly=false`.

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581659/defining-permissions-on-a-kubernetes-mounted-volume-in-spark-executor/73672387#73672387) I asked how to fix this and the question gets clearly answered.